# Infinite product whose entries tend to 1 rapidly

Tags: analysis, infinite-product

Does the following infinite product converge and what is the limit if it exists?

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^i}{2^i+1}$$

Comment: Suppose the limit is $L$. What Is $\log_2(L)$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\sum (i - \log_2(2^i+1))$. It seems to be tending to $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: The sequence of partial products decreases monotonically and is bounded below by 0, so by the monotone convergence theorem the infinite product converges.

Comment: @DavidH Can we find the limit in a representable form?

Comment: @newbie I don't know.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalNumberTheorem.html (formula (8) in the case $t=-1$, $x = 1/2$).

Comment: Specifically, your product is $2^{-1/24} \dfrac{\eta(i \ln(2)/(2 \pi))}{\eta(i \ln(2)/\pi)}$ where $\eta$ is the Dedekind eta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try writing it as $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1 + 2^{-i}}$.

Comment: I have obtained $\sum log(1+2^{-i})$. How to precede further?

Comment: @newbie $\log(1+x)\le x$ for $x>-1$.

Comment: @V.C. So the infinite product is bounded by $e^{-1}$ and $1$?

Comment: @newbie: Yes. It is easiest if we flip the thing over, then no negatives. The log of the partial product to $n$ is $\lt \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$.

Comment: @newbie Yes, it is bounded by $e^{-1}$ and $1$. Alternatively, we can use the inequality $x/(1+x)\le\log(1+x)$ for $x>-1$ and obtain the upper bound $\exp(-\sum_{i=1}^\infty(1+2^i)^{-1})\approx0.466$.